# Let f be an irreducible cubic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ with atmost one real root and K...

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let f be an irreducible cubic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ with at most one real root and K be the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing the roots of f. Then prove that $[K: \mathbb{Q}]$ is an even number.

The question was asked in my quiz yesterday and is objective and had 3 other options which i proved or contradicted, but I am struck on this and need help.

I have been following algebra by Emil Artin.

Comment: This has been answered already. Please try to search before posting. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3641958/let-f-be-an-irreducible-cubic-polynomial-over-mathbb-q-with-exactly-one-rea).

Comment: An irreducible cubic over $\mathbb{Q } $  has either splitting field of degree $3$ or degree $6$. Can you distinguish these two cases?